# How to declare an array with objects in the state ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wondering how to make new blank array with objects in the state and how to add element in it with setState.

I want the array so:

```
newhosts: [
      {
      activityState : "",
      platform: "",
      pushDate: "",
      name: "",
      ip: "",
      software: [{
        vulnerability: {
          link: "",
          desc: "",
          cvss: "",
          cve: ""
        },
        vulnerable: '',
        cpe: "",
        version: "",
        vendor: "",
        name: ""

      }]
      }
    ]
```

Is it okay , so to declare the array in the state?
How can I add later description oder items(for example description of the host and then description of all software elements on it). And how can I add for example two softwares to the same host?

```
 const namearray= this.state.filteredhosts.map(host=> {
        return (
           host.software.map((sub, subindex) => { 

          if(selectedOption==="name" || selectedOption==="vendor") {
            if(sub[selectedOption]=== writtenOption){


            newState.push(host.meta.name)
            newState.push(host.meta.ip)
            newState.push(sub.name) 
            newState.push(sub.vendor)
          }

         }
          else { 
            if(sub.vulnerable===true){
            newState.push(sub.vulnerability[selectedOption])}
            newState.push(host.meta.name)
            newState.push(host.meta.ip)  
          }
        })
        )
      })
```

Here I must replace this "newState.push" with your function, which save the data to the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having an array as a state-value is completely valid. Consider the sandbox I made for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/deeply-nested-inputs-mf70m

Your question gave me some inspiration and writing this out actually taught me a lot about handling nested inputs and how to update them.

This code will show you how to:

- Create a new `host` object and the corresponding inputs for
  the user to fill.
- Update a single host object, it's first layer such as fields `activityState`, `platform`,
  etc.
- Update a single `software` object inside a host, including the inner
  `vulnerability` object and outer-fields such as `vulnerable`, `cpe`, etc.
- Adding a new, additional `software` object to a host. And then updating
  those software objects.

Fill out the form with any combination of `hosts` and `software`, when you're finished hit the `Click to Log Hosts` button to print the finalized `state`.

### The code:

```
import React from "react";
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    newhosts: [
      {
        activityState: "",
        platform: "",
        pushDate: "",
        name: "",
        ip: "",
        software: [
          {
            vulnerability: {
              link: "",
              desc: "",
              cvss: "",
              cve: ""
            },
            vulnerable: "",
            cpe: "",
            version: "",
            vendor: "",
            name: ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  handleOnChange = (event, hostindex, layer, softwareIndex) => {
    const { newhosts } = this.state;
    const copiedHosts = [...newhosts];
    const updatedHosts = copiedHosts.map((host, index) => {
      //find mathcing index to update that item
      if (hostindex === index) {
        //determine what layer of data we need to update
        if (layer === 1) {
          //we need to update activityState, platform etc...
          return {
            ...host,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
          };
        } else if (layer === 2) {
          //now we need to find the matching software item to update
          let updatedSoftware = copiedHosts[hostindex].software.map(
            (software, sIndex) => {
              if (softwareIndex === sIndex) {
                return {
                  ...software,
                  [event.target.name]: event.target.value
                };
              } else {
                return {
                  ...software
                };
              }
            }
          );
          return {
            ...host,
            software: updatedSoftware
          };
        } else if (layer === 3) {
          //now we need to find the matching software item to update
          let updatedSoftware = copiedHosts[hostindex].software.map(
            (software, sIndex) => {
              if (softwareIndex === sIndex) {
                return {
                  ...software,
                  vulnerability: {
                    ...software.vulnerability,
                    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
                  }
                };
              } else {
                return {
                  ...software
                };
              }
            }
          );
          return {
            ...host,
            software: updatedSoftware
          };
        }
      } else {
        //return all other hosts
        return host;
      }
    });
    this.setState({
      newhosts: updatedHosts
    });
  };

  createNewHostsForm = () => {
    const { newhosts } = this.state;

    return newhosts.map((host, hostIndex) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h4>{`Host ${hostIndex + 1}`}</h4>
          {Object.entries(host).map(([key, value], lvl1Index) => {
            if (Array.isArray(value)) {
              const secondLayerInputs = [...value];
              return (
                <div>
                  <strong>software:</strong>
                  {secondLayerInputs.map((input, softwareIndex) => {
                    return Object.entries(input).map(([lvl2Key, lvl2Value]) => {
                      if (typeof lvl2Value === "string") {
                        return (
                          <div>
                            <label>{lvl2Key}</label>{" "}
                            <input
                              value={lvl2Value}
                              name={lvl2Key}
                              onChange={e =>
                                this.handleOnChange(
                                  e,
                                  hostIndex,
                                  2,
                                  softwareIndex
                                )
                              }
                            />
                          </div>
                        );
                      } else {
                        const thirdLayerInputs = { ...lvl2Value };
                        return Object.entries(thirdLayerInputs).map(
                          ([lvl3Key, lvl3Value]) => {
                            return (
                              <div>
                                <label>{lvl3Key}</label>{" "}
                                <input
                                  name={lvl3Key}
                                  value={lvl3Value}
                                  onChange={e =>
                                    this.handleOnChange(
                                      e,
                                      hostIndex,
                                      3,
                                      softwareIndex
                                    )
                                  }
                                />
                              </div>
                            );
                          }
                        );
                      }
                    });
                  })}
                  <button onClick={() => this.addSoftwareToHost(hostIndex)}>
                    Add Software
                  </button>
                </div>
              );
            } else {
              return (
                <div>
                  <label>{key}</label>{" "}
                  <input
                    value={value}
                    onChange={e => this.handleOnChange(e, hostIndex, 1)}
                    name={key}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            }
          })}
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  addNewHost = () => {
    const newHostObj = {
      activityState: "",
      platform: "",
      pushDate: "",
      name: "",
      ip: "",
      software: [
        {
          vulnerability: {
            link: "",
            desc: "",
            cvss: "",
            cve: ""
          },
          vulnerable: "",
          cpe: "",
          version: "",
          vendor: "",
          name: ""
        }
      ]
    };
    this.setState({
      newhosts: [...this.state.newhosts, newHostObj]
    });
  };

  addSoftwareToHost = hostIndex => {
    const { newhosts } = this.state;
    const copiedHosts = [...newhosts];
    const newSoftwareObj = {
      vulnerability: {
        link: "",
        desc: "",
        cvss: "",
        cve: ""
      },
      vulnerable: "",
      cpe: "",
      version: "",
      vendor: "",
      name: ""
    };

    const updatedHosts = copiedHosts.map((host, index) => {
      if (hostIndex === index) {
        return {
          ...host,
          software: [...host.software, newSoftwareObj]
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...host
        };
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      newhosts: updatedHosts
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(this.state.newhosts);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.createNewHostsForm()}
        <div style={{ margin: "25px 0px" }}>
          {" "}
          <button onClick={this.addNewHost}>Add Host</button>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Click to Log Hosts</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was my idea. Can u help me now with advice how to integrate it with my code? I have a function, with to say "for" function and for which loop I become all elements  ( I updated the question)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have this data

```
state = {
   newhosts : [{hostdata1}, {hostdata2}]
}
```

### add host description

```
function addHostDescription = (selectHostIp) => {
    const copyState = [...this.state.newhosts];
    const hostIndex = copyState.findIndex(host => host.ip === selectHostIp);
    copyState[hostIndex] = {...copyState[hostIndex], description : 'description content'};
    this.setState({
        newhosts : copyState
    })
}
```

### add new software

```
function addNewSoftware = (selectHostIp, newSoftware) => {
    const copyState = [...this.state.newhosts];
    const hostIndex = copyState.findIndex(host => host.ip === selectHostIp);
    copyState[hostIndex].software.push(newSoftware);
    this.setState({
        newhosts : copyState
    })
}
```

#### add new host

```
function addNewHost = (newHost) => {
    const copyState = [...this.state.newhosts];
    copyState.push(newHost);
    this.setState({
        newhosts : copyState
    })
}
```

Comment: and how can I add two different softwares to the same host?

Comment: just call addNewSoftware two times with new data

Comment: ok maybe this can work but at the beginning my array is empty?

Comment: and I must save for each host every single element  at the beginning
for software is exactly the same , I must add each element single

Comment: If you start newhosts : [], just call addNewHost. Then, host will be added